# Custom CEWP loaded in HTML page layout causes other webparts to disappear

Tags: 2013, page-layout, cewp

I have a custom html page layout.  I've saved a custom webpart and added it to the Webpart Gallery.  The custom webpart has simple HTML [a table with a few `<i>` classes to utilize Font Awesome], and I've added this webpart to my page layout using the Snippet Gallery.  There are a couple of other webparts on the page layout [standard OOTB webparts such as a calendar, task list, and newsfeed].  When I uploaded the page layout and checked the preview, I could see my Custom Webpart displaying properly.  However, if I create a new page based on that Page Layout, there are a few things that happen:

a.) the Table in the custom webpart is not visible.
b.) The other webparts on the page which have titles are suddenly called 'Untitled' and in the Newsfeed's case, it disappears.
c.) I want to note that the webpart automatically wraps my html table in a `![CDATA[` tag, however, I do note in the preview that the closing `]]>` tag is included.  So I'm assuming the issue is in the CDATA.
Does anyone know what could be the possible cause of this?